# Cannot create perlplu function

Tags: security, postgresql-9.1, functions, perl

Running PostgreSQL 9.1.8 on Xubuntu 12.04, installed from the repos.

From the shell, I have executed:

```
createlang plperl db_name;
createlang plperlu db_name;
```

As the superuser running `psql`, I have executed:

```
GRANT ALL ON LANGUAGE plperl TO account_name;
GRANT ALL ON LANGUAGE plperlu TO account_name;
```

The `pg_language` table reveals:

```
select lanname,lanpltrusted from pg_language where lanname like 'plperl%';

"plperl";t
"plperlu";t
```

When I create the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hostname()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  use Sys::Hostname;
  return hostname;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plperlu IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION get_hostname()
  OWNER TO account_name;
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  Unable to load Sys/Hostname.pm into plperl at line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line 2.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "get_hostname"
```

Yet the following works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hostname()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  return '127.0.0.1';
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plperlu IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION get_hostname()
  OWNER TO account_name;
```

The following Perl script works as expected from the shell:

```
use Sys::Hostname;
print hostname;
```

I tried to run the function as an anonymous block:

```
DO $$
  use Sys::Hostname;
  print hostname;
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

This returned the same error as before, with this additional information:

```
ERROR: Unable to load Sys/Hostname.pm into plperl at line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line 3.
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/Perl anonymous code block
```

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html), error 42601 is a syntax error.

I see no syntax error.

Furthermore, the function loaded fine with the superuser account when I imported the database:

```
psql -d db_name -U account_name -W -f db-dump.sql > import.log 2> error.log
```

I tried to simplify the code to no avail:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hostname() RETURNS text AS
$$
  use Sys::Hostname;
  return hostname;
$$
LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Same error as before.

What I don't understand is why, according to the error message, PostgreSQL is trying to load the code into `plperl` instead of `plperlu`.

Any ideas?

#### Update #1

Note that the postgres user is a Superuser:

```
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `plperlu` being untrusted, the account requires superuser authorization:

```
DROP LANGUAGE plperl;
DROP LANGUAGE plperlu;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRUSTED LANGUAGE plperlu;
UPDATE pg_language set lanpltrusted = true where lanname='plperlu';
GRANT ALL ON LANGUAGE plperlu TO account_name WITH GRANT OPTION;
ALTER USER account_name WITH SUPERUSER;
```

I do not know if `plperl` and `plperlu` are allowed to be installed at the same time, so I dropped the former. The function can now be created.